# find all substring between two char (...) delimiters using shell script

Tags: string, shell, unix

I want find all substring between '(' and ')' delimiters using shell script

```
ex: a string (123).....(abc)...(0000).....

123
abc
0000
```

I want to extract all substring from the string and use grep like this:

```
grep -o -P "(?<=()(.*?)(?=))"
```

and how to assign the output values that match the conditions to the variables
x=123
y=abc
...
Thanks

Comment: How is this related to Python?

Comment: @MichaelButscher probably it's related to python shell

Comment: @FarhangAmaji "shell script" is often used as a synonym to a bash script, not a Python script.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I know, but I have no clue that in SE is it ok or not, because if u look at it, it's [python],[shell] and it is not [shell] in common sense. so if u are aware of all rules here please modify the tags

Comment: @FarhangAmaji Then "shell" and "shell script" would have much broader definitions than I thought. I really love Python but I wouldn't want to have it as everyday shell.

Answer (score 1):

As your question is confusing regarding the language to use, using bash:

```
echo "a string (123).....(abc)...(0000)..... <br/>" | grep -P "(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\))" -o
```

The same logic can be used in Python

```
import re

data = "a string (123).....(abc)...(0000)..... <br/>"
print(re.findall("(?<=\\()(.*?)(?=\\))", data))
```

---

**Output**

```
123
abc
0000
```

---

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\()` : positive lookbehind for `(`
- `(.*?)` : match everything in a non-greedy way and capture it.
- `(?=\))` : positive lookahead for `)`

Answer (score 0):

```
strr='a string (123).....(abc)...(0000)..... <br/>'
strr=strr.split('(')
plist=[]
for s in range(1,len(strr)):
    plist.append(strr[s].split(')')[0])
print(plist)
```